# How does Visual Studio choose which analyzers to run?

Tags: visual-studio, analysis, visual-studio-2022

I am working on a project which has some logging errors. Last week I could compile this project just fine, even though it has "warning as errors" turned on. Today, I get `CA2017` warnings, which are treated as errors, and prevent me compiling. For some reason, nobody else on my team seems to get these warnings / errors.

What mechanism does Visual Studio use to decide which analyzers to run? I know `.editorconfig` files can be added to the solution / projects, but this can't be the only mechanism, or everybody in my team would have the same problem.

Obviously, we need to fix these errors, but I'd like to know why I get a different experience to team mates who are using the same Visual Studio on the same code. I can find no settings in Visual Studio options related to analysis that are any different for me than for my colleagues.

Comment: Are you using VS or VScode latest version and what is your operating system? This seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/5738) that is documented as fixed in the latest releases of VS.

Comment: Visual Studio Professional 2022 17.6.5

Comment: The bug looks eerily connected, but colleagues with the same version don't get warnings (most recent, well after March) and I just found if I deleted all of my settings in AppData it now picks it up but doesn't report it as an error. Actually, that has muddied the waters a bit.